# .NET Core NLog logging before BuildWebHost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nlog

I use NLog and I have created my own log provider for my application. I set the configuration up with NLog in the StartUp class.

I will show you how the Program.cs look right now.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configurationDic = CreateConfigurationDictionary(); 
      // In here it can throw an exception therefore I need to be able to log here

        var webHost = BuildWebHost(configurationDic, args);

        var applicationLogger = webHost.Services.GetService<IMyTestLogProvider>().ApplicationLogger;

        applicationLogger.LogInformation("*************** Start up ***************");

        webHost.Run();
    }
```

The logging works fine except that I need to log earlier in the main class. Any ideas how I get my application logger before building the web host?

I have seen example, https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2 , where I should be able to do:

```
var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

But my application don't know what NLogBuilder is though I have the NLog nuget packages installed.

Any ideas?

Best regards
Rob

Comment: What exactly are you doing *before* the web host that needs to be logged and that cannot be delayed later to when the host actually initializes? If you have a lot of things happening there, that might be a sign that your *web* application is doing too much that isn’t really related to a *web* application.

Comment: Notice https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/4.5.0-rc1 has been released. It should enable NLogBuilder for net461.

Answer (score 0):

> But my application don't know what NLogBuilder is though I have the NLog nuget packages installed.

Check your dependencies, you need:

- NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.5+ (currently beta04)
- NLog 4.4.12+ (e.g. NLog 4.5 beta) - no NLog 5! - if not using .NET standard **1**
- If you're using .NET standard 1 (not .NET standard 2) - use NLog 5+  (currently beta)

Answer (score 0):

See updated Wiki for how to activate logging, before BuildWebHost (Update to NLog 4.5.0 RTM or newer)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // NLog: setup the logger first to catch all errors
    var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
    try
    {
        logger.Debug("init main");
        BuildWebHost(args).Run(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //NLog: catch setup errors
        logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
        NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs

Comment: Does not work! As original poster indicated "my application don't know what NLogBuilder". I  have nlog 4.5.6, core 2.0.3, even though this is an api/mvc I also tried adding nlog.web.aspnetcore 4.5.4.

Comment: @ginalster Thank you for pointing out the mistake. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Rolf's answer does not work because of a subtle difference.

> var logger = NLog.Web.LogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

should be

> var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // NLog: setup the logger first to catch all errors
    var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
    try
    {
        logger.Debug("init main");
        BuildWebHost(args).Run(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //NLog: catch setup errors
        logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
         // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit(Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

}